# gcloud docker pull fails with Untar exit status 2 unexpected fault address

Tags: docker, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

EDIT: A huge thank you @mattmoor for helping me debug the issue. After I had to create a new docker-machine. There was a problem with the docker daemon that must've arisen due to the first machine not being created correctly.

---

I am having trouble pulling images from another computer, both of which are running OSX Yosemite. Both machines have the docker daemon running, and have successfully authenticated with the desired project to pull from with

`gcloud auth login`

On my computer I am able to run:

`gcloud docker pull gcr.io/projectid/image-tag` without any issues.

However when I try to repeat this on another machine, I get a large error message that begins with:

`Error pulling image (tag-here) from gcr.io/projectid/image-tag, endpoint: https://gcr.io/v1/, Untar exit status 2 unexpected fault address 0xc208ce5d04
fatal error: faultr downloading dependent layers 
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0xc208ce5d04 pc=0x94109e]`

Followed by a goroutine 1 stack trace.

The docker version on both machines is 1.6.2, the client and server api version is 1.18, both Go versions are go1.4.2

The Google Cloud SDK version on both machines is 0.9.67, and both have the following components installed:

- bq 2.0.18
- bq-nix 2.0.18
- core 2015.06.30
- core-nix 2015.06.02
- gcloud 2015.06.30
- gcutil-msg 2015.06.09
- gsutil 4.13
- gsutil-nix 4.12
- preview 2015.06.30

and the machine that works also has these extra components installed:

- alpha 2015.06.30
- beta 2015.06.30
- kubectl
- kubectl-darwin-x86_64 0.18.1

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm truly baffled as to why I can't pull from the gcr registry on the other machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm baffled too, this looks like Docker dying trying to untar the blob, and I haven't seen that before.

Would you mind starting a thread with gcr-contact@google.com, as this may take a little debugging, and email will be a bit easier for the back-and-forth.

We can update this with what we find, if that works for you?